# Embed editable Google Docs spreadsheet without footer sheet toolbar

Tags: google-sheets

I am sharing an editable Google sheet on my website (shared with any user on Google sheet side), using https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[hash]/edit?rm=minimal
Adding the rm=minimal allows to remove the Google navigation and toolbar at the top.

Is there a way to remove the bottom bar allowing to add new sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.

A document may be shared as editable, or shared as not editable, or not shared at all.

There is not fine grained control over prohibiting the addition/deletion of individual sheets in the document.

That's why there's no URI argument to hide the UI elements relating to this feature — the feature is one of the things you're explicitly granting access to, by making the share editable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interesting though that the rm=minimal parameter allows to completely hide the navigation and tool bar at the top. I am sure the shortcuts to call Google sheet functions still work, but not a concern at this point. My goal is to share some kind of playground to run calculation scenarios in a sheet. I locked the sheet for edition except some cells with values that can be edited.

Comment: @PhilippeSchulligen Navigation and toolbar are not shareable things. They're not part of the document. That's just a meta UI element. Worksheets are a fundamental part of the document. Like cells, or the text inside them. It's not a valid comparison.

Comment: Moreover the `rm=minimal` is not an argument that you can control. If you where to share with me I could just drop that parameter from the URL. And see it in a complete way.